# jquery datepicker from partial not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, uidatepicker

hello i have a datepicker that is working perfectly alone, code is like:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="uidatepicker/themes/blitzer/jquery.ui.all.css">
    <script src="uidatepicker/jquery-1.5.1.js"></script>
    <script src="uidatepicker/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
    <script src="uidatepicker/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>

    <script src="uidatepicker/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="uidatepicker/demos.css">


    <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
            showOn: "both",
            buttonImage: "uidatepicker/calendar.gif",
            buttonImageOnly: true
        });
    });
    </script>


<form method="post" action="saveEvent.php">
<p>Titulo del evento:</p>
<input type="text" name="title" value=""  class="text-input medium-input datepicker"/>
<p>Descripcion:</p>
<textarea name="message"></textarea>
<p>Fecha:</p>
<input type="text" name="date" value="" id="datepicker"/>
<p>Locacion:</p>
<select name="locationId" class="small-input">
  <option value="">--- Selecciona ---</option>
            <option value="3">La charanguita</option>
            <option value="7">H20</option>
            <option value="8">Bleu</option>
      </select>
<p>Url del icono: (150x135px)</p>
<input type="text" name="smallIconUrl" value=""  class="text-input medium-input"/>

<p><input type="submit" value="Nuevo Evento" class="button"  /></p>

</form>
```

and i am loading it from another file as in:

```
    $('#EventsContent').load('partials/newEvent.php');
```

Problem is datepicker never appears no matter what i tried, this has been nailing for me for like 3 days now.

What is the exact problem impeding the correct operation of jquery ui datepicker??+

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. which input text you use datepicker? I saw you have an id="datepicker " and class="datepicker "?
2. I replace the ' to " , I test the code in browser "IE,FireFox,GoogleChrome", it's work.
3. I use JQuery 1.5.2 & jquery-ui-1.8.10, but I think version is not a big problem.

### 4. I have the other ideal, you can re-Bind the datepicker event when you load complete like this:

```
$('#EventsContent').load('partials/newEvent.php', function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        showOn: "both",
        buttonImage: "uidatepicker/calendar.gif",
        buttonImageOnly: true
    });    
});
```

---

When you use the datatpicker after you load the partial , you must re-bind, but JQuery live() function can help us to do that things, see http://api.jquery.com/live/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#datepicker").live("click", function () {
            $(this).datepicker({
                showOn: "both",
                buttonImage: "uidatepicker/calendar.gif",
                buttonImageOnly: true
            }).focus();
        });
    });
</script>
```

instead of :

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        showOn: "both",
        buttonImage: "uidatepicker/calendar.gif",
        buttonImageOnly: true
    });
});
```

Comment: Result of expression '$('#datepicker').live' [undefined] is not a function. i have tried putting into the main page and also on the partial, i just keep getting that error... thanks for your quick answer...

Comment: @Carlos Barbosa: I modify ' to " ,maybe you can test again : )